# Keep getting this error when running this code

Tags: discord.js, roles

I'm trying to make verification channel where users will verify themselves using reactions.
I tried fetching messages from the verify channel and trying to do this code:

```
 const mReaction = new Discord.MessageReaction();
 const message = mReaction.message;
 const verified = 'verifiedID';
 const unverified = 'unverifiedID';
 if(message.reactions.cache.find(r => r.emoji === '✅') || message.channel.id == 'channelID'){
     message.member.roles.add(verified);
     message.member.roles.remove(unverified);
 }
```

When I run the code I keep getting:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'me' of undefined
    at new MessageReaction (D:\Users\Rastik\Desktop\discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageReaction.js:35:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Users\Rastik\Desktop\discord bot\main.js:98:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

So I would like to ask you guys to help me, If anyone would be that awesome to try help me I would really appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you are showing the right code, no where in the code block is there a call on `.me`, show line 98 (like the error says) and lines surrounding 98 that are relevant.

Comment: At line 98 starts independent code block and that code block is the whole code block I have sent.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you are creating a `MessageReaction` out of thin air,

`const mReaction = new Discord.MessageReaction();`

If you look at the docs, it shows you would need the client, the data and the message.

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction

`const message = mReaction.message` how would it know which message the reaction refers to? You don't define anything

All in all this code makes no sense.

If you want to do a verification message reaction system you will need to listen to the `messageReactionAdd` event, but since that event listens to only cached messages you will need to either use `raw` event or partials

I will show the partial way.

Main file:

```js
const client = new Client({ partials: ["REACTION", "MESSAGE"]});
```

And then you will need to handle the `messageReactionAdd` event somehow,

```js
client.on("messageReactionAdd", async (reaction, user) => {
  if(reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
  //you should have one message with the checkmark emoji, that users need to press
  //to join, insert the msg id here
  if(reaction.message.id !== "id") return;


  //now you validate the user, if they have the role already return if not add.
});
```

Comment: thanks for answer, I figured it out few hours before I noticed your comment here, but still thanks a lot for trying to help me :)